# TweenLite: Spamming clicks breaks animations

Tags: gsap

I have some tabs that when clicked on, the content is animated in/out using `TweenLite`.  If you click the tabs really fast it will break the animations and eventually no content is visible.  I tried `killTweensOf` but it didn't help.

Here is all the animation code:

```js
TweenLite.killTweensOf($elOldContent);
TweenLite.killTweensOf($elTargetContent);

//Move current tab content out of frame to the left and fade out.
TweenLite.to($elOldContent, .75, {left:"-300px",opacity:"0",onComplete:function() {
    //Hide, reset the position and opacity.
    $elOldContent.removeClass('active').hide().css({"left":"0","opacity":"1"});
    }
});

//Make the new content active, set opacity to zero and move off screen to right in preparation for grand entrance
$elTargetContent.addClass('active').css({"opacity":"0","left":"300px"}).show();
//Move into frame from right, fade in
TweenLite.to($elTargetContent, .75, {left:"0px",opacity:"1"});
```

Here is a cap of the behavior:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What has worked for me in the past is to set some sort of animation state and test if the animation is active, if it is not active you can fire your TL animation if it is active you basically return false.

Try something like

```
let isAnim = false;

if (isAnim === false) {
    //Animation is not running run 

    TweenLite.to($elOldContent, .75, {left:"-300px", opacity:"0", 
        onStart: function(){
            isAnim = true;
        },
        onComplete: function(){
            isAnim = false;

            //Hide, reset the position and opacity.
            $elOldContent.removeClass('active').hide().css({"left":"0","opacity":"1"});
        }
    );
}
```

The user can click as much as they want but the animation won't get out of sync